# What value does this line store char c = str[sizeof(int*)] ;?

Tags: c, pointers

```
char str[] = "Stanford University";
char a = str[1];
char b = *(char *)((int *)str + 3);
char c = str[sizeof(int *)];
```

What are the char values of `a`, `b` and `c`?

```
a = 't'
```

value of `b` is `'v'` and `c` is `' '` (space). But how come `c` is space? size of `int *` is 4 bytes or 8 bytes.  We will have different values in both the cases. Also, in `b` it is pointing to `s[12]` but how the whole line is executed, i mean first it is typecasted by `int *` and then by `char *` and then we are dereferencing or we are doing something else?

Comment: Have you... tried printing out those values and trying to figure out why they're those values? (In my testing environment, `a=116, b=118, c=32`)

Comment: Yes @AKX , i tried printing the values for b it gives 'v' and for c it prints nothing . For char b i have some vague explanation but for c i am bit confused .

Comment: c = ` ` a space, address size of pointers is 8 bytes. `c = str[sizeof(int*) + 1]` will have `U`. Fiddle with those numbers; even better use a debugger, to evaluate many expressions.

Comment: `sizeof(int*)` is architecture-dependent. Cannot answer this in general terms.

Comment: What do _you_ think these values are?

Comment: @Jabberwocky b is 'v' and c is ' ' (space ) . But how C is space size of int* is 4 bytes or 8 bytes  We will have different values in both the cases . Also , in b it is pointing to s[12] but how the whole line is executed i mean first it is typecasted by int* and then by char * and then we are dereferencing or we are doing something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first value is always `'t'` as it is the second character in the C string stored in `str`.

The second value depends on the size of `int` on the target platforms. Hint: most modern platforms use 32-bit `int` and 8-bit `char`.

The third value depends on the size of pointers to `int`. Hint: pointers can have a different size than `int`, on modern platforms they usually have 64 bits.

Th values you observe on your platform at consistent with `int` having a size of 4 bytes (32-bit) and `int *` having a size of 8 bytes (64-bit). This is the case on current 64-bit systems.

Here is the explanation for the second expression:

To evaluate `*(char *)((int *)str + 3)`, the compiler first converts `str` to a pointer to `int`, which might be misaligned<sup>(*)</sup>, then computes the address of the fourth `int` in an array pointed to by `(int *)str`, hence 12 bytes from the beginning of this array, then this address is converted back to `char *`, keeping the same address. Finally, `*` reads the character pointed to by the latter, hence `str[3 * 4]` ie. the letter `'v'`.

The behavior is simpler to explain for the third expression:

`char c = str[sizeof(int *)];` just reads the character at offset `sizeof(int *)` which is `8` or your system, so `c` contains `' '`, the space between `Stanford` and `University`.

Remember that both the second and third expressions are implementation defined:

- on ancien MS/DOS systems using small model, you would have `b = 'r'` and `c = 'a'`, and using medium and large model, `b = 'r'` and `c = 'f'`;
- on old 32-bit Windows, Mac and linux systems, you would have `b = 'v'` and `c = 'f'`;
- on some exotic Cray systems with 64-bit `int`, computing `b` would have undefined behavior;
- on some embedded DSP processors, you could even have `b = 'n'` and `c = 't'`.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> *the misaligned pointer will not be dereferenced as an `int *`, but even just computing an invalid address has undefined behavior so something weird could happen on exotic systems. If your target is a personal computer running Windows, macOS or linux, this risky address computation should not pose a problem.*

Comment: Suppose we have taken size of int = 4 bytes , size of short = 2 bytes , size of char = 1 byte and size of pointer = 4 bytes . Now can you please elaborate

Comment: @VishalKumar then you should be able to figure out the third one

Comment: The second is definitely implementation-dependent, but may also result in undefined behavior if the alignment of `str` is not correct for an int. Appendix J:"Conversion between two pointer types produces a result that is incorrectly aligned"

Comment: size of pointers to int =4 Bytes then it should return me F right ?

Comment: @VishalKumar **if** the size of an `int *` is 4 bytes.  It's most likely 8 bytes.

Comment: Notably, some systems might yield a hardware exception by merely creating a misaligned pointer, regardless of if it is de-referenced or not. So it's potentially already UB during the pointer conversion itself. So this example isn't a good snippet to use for the purpose of teaching.

Comment: @Lundin: I'm afraid you are a bit too academic, systems used for teaching and production do not have any such behavior nowadays. Once the beginners grasp the concepts of memory layout, array, pointers, variable scoping, control structures, functions, argument passing and value returning, recursion, algorithm complexity... then they can discover the wisdom of the C Standard and how it addresses portability issues and non standard architectures. They should be warned that the language is more subtle than it looks, but not to the point of giving up.

Comment: @chqrlie It's not really caused by the C language, but by various more or less exotic ISA. I believe some MIPS microcontrollers behave as I just described and they seem somewhat popular still among schools. If a student gets a mysterious bus error out of the blue during lab assignment and can't figure out why, then what?

Comment: @Lundin: `char b = *(char *)((int *)str + 3);` is part of his assignment. I provided an explanation for how it seems to work on his system. I am going to add an extra warning regarding potential UB :)

Comment: I just wish that teachers could do "here is a well-written, well-defined piece of quality C source code, analyse it, what does it do?" Rather than "here's some sloppy, poorly-defined hack, what does it do?" Including the tiresome "what is the result of i=i++" or spending half the beginner class trying to understand useless and dangerous recursion...